# angular controller function does not return results from one function to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

in my controller i have a function

```
$scope.orderHistory = {};
$scope.results = {};

var getHistory = function (max,offset)
 {
    //do some stuff
    $scope.orderHistory = data.entities;

    angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory,function(value)
    {
        $scope.results = getResults(value.id);
        console.log($scope.results);

    });

 }


 var getResults = function(id)
 {

    api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then ( function (results)
        {
            return results.data;

        });


 };
```

the problem i run into is the getResults function does not seem to actually return the data and have it set to $scope.results inside the getHistory function.

When i do a console.log in (results.data) inside the .then part of getResults function i see the results. Can anyone help me understand why it is not returning the results even though it exists and what i can do to fix it

Comment: You are expecting `$scope.resulsts` the array of results?

Comment: yes $scope.results should be the results and when i do a console.log($scope.results) i should see the results returned from getResults()

Comment: is orderHistory array or is it an dictionary?

Comment: orderHistory is an array

Comment: do you see an empty object in your view? if you console log the results in means you have it and everything works in the controller.

Comment: console.log($scope.results) return undefined in the console while

console.log(results.data); inside of the .then in getResults function shows teh correct data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function in `then(function(){...})` is executed [asynchronously](http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript), and the containing `getResults` function won't wait for it to return. More specifically, `api.getHistoryData` seems to return a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

You can use Angular's data binding to work around this:

```
var getHistory = function (max,offset)
 {
    //do some stuff
    $scope.orderHistory = data.entities;

    angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory,function(value)
    {
        getResults(value.id);    
    });

 }

var getResults = function(id)
 {   
    api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then ( function (results) {
            $scope.results = results.data;
        });
 };
```

And then in your template use something like:

```
<button ng-click="getHistory(0, 0)"></button>
{{results}}
```

Comment: This isnt anything to do with the view though. Im trying to get the results from getResults function and use it as part of my getHistory function

Comment: @Yeak I updated my answer, you'll need to understand asynchronous javascript (see first link in my answer) to understand why your approach didn't work.

Comment: I understand asynchronous vs synchronous. I am new to angular though and your answer doesnt really tell me how to solve the issue.

Comment: Well, I mean you also need to know what a callback function and a promise is. Also, as long as you don't tell me why my answer isn't working for you there is little I can do...

Comment: this answer is correct...you can't return a value from within a callback in the `then` for `api.getHistoryData` and expect `getResults` to return it to `getHistory`...

Answer (score 4):

Lets see if I can clarify how promises work, and what might be throwing you off here:

When you say:

```
$scope.results = getResults(value.id);
```

That means, assign the return value of getResults to the **$scope.results** variable. Now let us take a look at your **getResults** function.

```
 var getResults = function(id) {
    api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then(function (results) {
            return results.data;
    });
 };
```

Now notice a few things:

1. The getResults function does not have a return statement. That means there is nothing returned from getResults to be assigned to $scope.results.
2. The getResults function itself makes an asynchronous request. That means, if when the function executes, and when the results come back are two different points in time.
3. Finally, your return statement is not inside the **getResults** function (technically it is), but is in fact inside a function inside the **getResults** function. Thus, the return **results.data** is for the **function(results) {}** and not for **getResults**
4. Also, notice if it had worked as you would have expected it to, you would keep overriding the value of **$scope.results** each time the server responded. That's probably not what you want

Let us modify the getResults function to clarify this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory, function(value) {
    console.log('1 - Get results for ', value.id);
    getResults(value.id);    
});
 var getResults = function(id) {
    console.log('2 - GetResults called');
    api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then(function (results) {
            console.log('3 - Get results has data');
            return results.data;
    });
 };
```

If we had code like the above, then the console.logs for 1 and 2 would get printed first, all together, and then at some later point, all the 3's would get printed together. This is because JavaScript is asynchronous and non-blocking, which means it will continue executing without waiting for the responses to come back.

So instead, to get this to work like you expect it to, you need to leverage Promises in AngularJS, which allow you a hook to know when the server response has come back. It offers us a way of working with asynchronous events across functions. So if you modify your code as follows:

```
angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory, function(value) {
    getResults(value.id).then(function(results) {
        $scope.results[value.id] = results.data;
    });    
});
 var getResults = function(id) {
    return api.getHistoryData(id);
 };
```

So we return a promise from **getResults**, and then when the promise is completed, we use the value and set it on $scope.results in the main function.

Hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you aren't using the promise correctly:

```
$scope.orderHistory = {};
$scope.results = {};

var getHistory = function (max,offset)
 {
    //do some stuff
    $scope.orderHistory = data.entities;

    angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory,function(value)
    {
        // get results returns a promise
        // we use the promise to set $scope.results
        getResults(value.id).then(function(results){
            $scope.results = results.data;
        });      
    });

 }

 // returns a promise
 var getResults = function(id)
 {
    return api.getHistoryData(id);
 };
```

`$scope.results` will be changed only after the promise is resolved.

Also, the way it is currently written, `$scope.results` will be overwritten for each `value.id`. If that is not your intention I'd turn it into an array and `push` each new value into it.

Answer (score 1):

Lets be clear, your `orderHistory` and `results` variables are objects, not arrays. The angular.forEach function allows you to iterate over both arrays and object properties; it does not mean the object being iterated is an array. Elad is correct in stating that your results variable will be overwritten for each iteration.

If you do want to keep all the results from your `getResults` function, you need to instantiate results as an array; and to have your view reflect the results, push them into your scope variable directly from the async result.

```
$scope.orderHistory = {};
$scope.results = [];

var getHistory = function (max,offset)
 {
    //do some stuff
    $scope.orderHistory = data.entities;

    angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory,function(value)
    {
        getResults(value.id);
    });

 }


 var getResults = function(id)
 {
    api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then ( function (results)
        {
            $scope.results.push(results);
        });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

just fix `getResults`, add `return` to it

```
var getResults = function(id)
 {
    return api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then ( function (results)
        {
            return results.data;

        });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 points.
First, getResults returns nothing, it just process chain of promisses. We can change getResults to return promiss which will return result:

```
var getResults = function(id)
 {
    return api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then ( function (results)
        {
            return results.data;

        });
 };
```

Second, from angular version 1.2 (not exactly sure if from this version) angular do not resolve promisses automaticaly so you must to do it yourself:

```
angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory,function(value)
{
    getResults(value.id).then(function(results){
       $scope.results = results;
       console.log($scope.results);
   })
});
```

The whole code:

```
$scope.orderHistory = {};
$scope.results = {};
var getHistory = function (max,offset)
 {
    //do some stuff
    $scope.orderHistory = data.entities;
    angular.forEach($scope.orderHistory,function(value)
    {
        getResults(value.id).then(function(results){
           $scope.results = results;
           console.log($scope.results);
       })     
    });
 }
 // returns a promise
 var getResults = function(id)
 {
   return api.getHistoryData(id)
        .then ( function (results)
        {
            return results.data;
        });
 };
```